# how to reopen git console in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, console

I closed git console,and I want to known how to reopen it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that this isn't specific to Git: it applies regardless of what version control system you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From IntelliJ's [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.3/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#6da6385d):

> The Console tab only appears when you execute version control-related
> commands. If you close this tab, all previous input will be lost.

It also states there that you can open it with `Alt + 9`

Comment: It opens the panel, not the console tab. But yeah. Accidentally closing console is not great.

Comment: You can reopen it by executing a command like `git fetch`, as stated above